# Start only a socat process when integrating with systemd

Tags: centos, systemd, process, socat

I want to run a "socat" command to replicate the information coming on port 162 to another machine and on the same port.

I added a systemd to do this process:

```
[Unit]
Description=Socat SNMP Traps 162

[Service]
User=root
Type=forking
StandardOutput=syslog
StandardError=syslog
SyslogIdentifier=socat-trap-162

ExecStart=sudo socat -d -d UDP-LISTEN:162,fork UDP:10.127.130.70:162
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

However, when running systemd, several PIDs are created,
as shown in [this screenshot of `ps | grep`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JAY8s.png).

Is there a possibility that only initial PIDs are created?

Because new PIDs are being created all the time.

Comment: (1) See `man 1 socat` and read what this `fork` option you used does. (2) Why `sudo`? (3) I know little about `iptables` and such, but maybe DNAT can be used instead of this `socat` of yours that runs in userspace.

Answer (score 0):

The UDP and UDP-LISTEN addresses create pseudo stream connections that need to be closed explicitly, because UDP does not transfer shutdown states,
or let them time out with option `-T <seconds>`.

When you have only one sender for the traps you can use your command line just without fork:

```
socat -d -d UDP-LISTEN:162 UDP:10.127.130.70:162
```

When you have multiple senders I'd recommend datagram mode:

```
socat -d -d UDP-RECV:162 UDP-SENDTO:10.127.130.70:162
```

Please note that UDP-RECV is unidirectional and works well with SNMP traps but not with SNMP commands.

Comment: Your solution of adding the -T parameter worked perfectly.

As the information only needs to reach the other machine, leaving the process open for 1 or 2 seconds is enough.

Thank you very much.